# "Friend"-ly Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, password

> All stories in this puzzle are fictions; the puzzle was made by myself.

My friend left me a puzzle. He gave me 5 papers, each had some information on it.

**#1**

| WORD SEARCH | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SOR | SUF | HYP | CAB | RAD | IUS |
| 2 | PRE | FIX | A | NET | VEN | SUB |
| 3 | IST | A | TER | ANT | DUN | LAT |
| 4 | EST | NOW | OKE | LEA | BRA | FER |
| 5 | ENE | KET | AIN | JUN | SIX | TOR |
| 6 | GEN | TRA | NSI | TED | ROW | BRO |

**#2**

| Board of Peace | T | Y | W |  | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | - | - | X | - | - |
| R | - | - | - | - | - |
| Z | - | X | - | - | - |
| F | - | - | - | X | - |
| K | - | - | - | - | - |

**#3**

| Unique<sub>-ish</sub> | -2 | 1 | -1 | 2 | R | Password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | i |  |  | d |  |  |
| 2 |  |  | i |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| E |  |  |  | r |  | Password |
| -1 |  |  |  |  | i |  |

**#4**

```
¥³b£b³“ÔTÄôT2Dut$ôâ2R4T‚$„â4DTD•%4š
```

**#5**

```
$ # Example Bash code
$ cat sentence[0]
$ Test 4
$ Who is it?
$
$ You entered: homepage
$ Suggestion: hmpg
```

He asked me what is the password; oh my, is it even *possible* to work out? But it seemed he's quite sure that it *can* be found, only using the information on the papers, and the Internet. "Even the end of Internet is useful," he said, "so what is the password?"

**Bonus** Answer the question in **#5** - who is it?

Comment: Does Q4 have anything to do with ASCII, Unicode or any other coding system?

Comment: @1357924680a **Yes**.

Comment: To someone who has seen a lot of text encoding mistakes, #4 looks broken. Would you mind posting the hex that we're supposed to get by "converting it to hex"?